# Haskell Servant: return String from file

Tags: haskell, servant

I have the following API:

```
type ServerAPI =
    "getBoard" :> Get '[JSON] String


serverRoutes :: Server ServerAPI
serverRoutes = 
    return (readFile "src/board.txt")
```

What I need to do is read a file and then return its content as the response for the request at "getBoard" route. It has proven to be very difficult, since `readFile` returns a `IO String`, not a `String`. Already looked for ways of returning a `String` from `readFile` and what I've found was this:

```
convertToString :: String -> String
convertToString str = str


type ServerAPI =
    "getBoard" :> Get '[JSON] String


serverRoutes :: Server ServerAPI
serverRoutes = do
    contents <- readFile "src/board.txt"
    let x = convertToString contents
    return x
```

But it keeps saying to me that `serverRoutes` is returning a `IO String`. I'm not sure if I'm doing the `convertToString` wrong or if the problem is with the `do` at `serverRoutes`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Server api` is `ServerT api Handler`, and `Handler` is an instance of `MonadIO`. Does that get you where you need to go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The monad you're in isn't `IO`, but it is an instance of `MonadIO`, so you use `liftIO`, like this:

```
serverRoutes :: Server ServerAPI
serverRoutes = liftIO $ readFile "src/board.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to do this for hours... I really need to get some theory before continuing with my project. Do you have some link where I can learn more about Monads?

Comment: @ThallesPortilho The problem here isn't finding a link, it's winnowing out the good links from the bad ones; check out the [wiki page listing monad tutorials](https://wiki.haskell.org/Tutorials#Using_monads) to see what I mean. My favorites are "The IO Monad for People who Simply Don't Care" and "All About Monads" but YMMV.